# Proper phrasing for - top X% of Y based on Z

Tags: expressions, numbers, phrasing

Suppose I have a list of pupils and 3 types of scores (academic, discipline, sports) for each student.

Is there a better way to write - the top 1% of students based on sports performance?

Comment: Maybe  "... ranked according to sport perfomance".

Comment: What's wrong with "the top 1% of students based on sports performance"? There are lots of different ways of expressing it, but not obviously ranked in order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're looking for a more concise phrasing, the single word 'by' is adequately clear:

> Only the top 15% of students by sports performance qualify for the scholarship.

Depending on context, 'in' can also be appropriate; in this case you only state the field, with the 'performance' implied:

> The competition team is in the top 10% in math and top 15% in English.